# ПЕревести синтаксис Mysql в Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть запрос

```
SELECT t1.user_id 
FROM likes t1
JOIN likes t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.like_user 
             AND t2.user_id = 1
             AND t1.like_user = 1
```

как мне его записать в Laravel?

пробую так

```
$users = DB::table(DB::raw('likes t1'))
       ->join(DB::raw('likes t2'), 't1.user_id', '=', 't2.like_user ')
       ->where('t2.user_id', '=', '1')
            ->where(' t1.like_user', '=', '1')->paginate(15);
```

но выдает

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'extremje_dating.DB::raw('likes t1')' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `DB::raw('likes t1')` inner join `DB::raw('likes t2')` on `t1`.`user_id` = `t2`.`like_user ` where `t2`.`user_id` = 1 and ` t1`.`like_user` = 1)
```

Comment: Может, не `DB::table(DB::raw('likes t1'))`, а просто `DB::raw('likes t1')`? Или вообще не париться - есть сырой SQL, там прям его и выполнять?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так

```
$users = DB::table('likes AS t1')
    ->join('likes AS t2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('t1.user_id', '=', 't2.like_user')
             ->where('t2.user_id', '=', '1')
             ->where('t1.like_user', '=', '1');
    })
    ->paginate(15);
```